# Execute custom script with run button

Tags: rubymine, dashing

I've started using RubyMine 7.0.0 and Dashing framework and question came up:
Is it possible somehow to run this commands "dashing start" from inside rubymine, so i can debug and see logs in Rubymine console ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a **Gem Command** Run Configuration for dashing. Just use `dashing` for **Gem name** and **executable name** and `s` or `start` for **arguments**. Works like a charm...